# Aligning values by decimal point

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, alignment

I have a `DataGridTemplate` which is bound to a double value "AverageWeight". This field doesn't have to have any decimal places but can have a maximum of 5 decimal places.

```
public double AverageWeight
{
    get { return _averageWeight; }
    set
    {
        _averageWeight = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => AverageWeight);
    }
}
```

The XAML for this is:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Width="4*"  Header="Avg. Weight">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="{Binding Path=AverageWeight}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

What I want to do is have these Average Weight values aligned at the decimal point without showing unnecessary trailing zeros. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will either need to pad it out with 0's using the format string property on the binding or build your own IValueConverter to handle the conversion using String.PadLeft to give it extra spaces.

This assumes that you are using a fixed width font, if you aren't then you are likely going to have to separate the fractional and integer component of the number and bind it into multiple text blocks.

Answer (score 0):

try with StringFormat

```
Content="{Binding Path=AverageWeight, StringFormat=N5}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the Label:

```
ContentStringFormat="{}{0:F5}"
```

It will create 5 zeroes if needed.